# Qnx View File descriptor Occupancy Information

Tags: qnx

I need to check the occupation of the File descriptor of a process in the qnx system
DCMD_PROC_MAPDEBUG_BASE
DCMD_PROC_PAGEDATA
DCMD_PROC_INFO
DCMD_PROC_STATUS
DCMD_PROC_TIDSTATUS
DCMD_PROC_TIMES
DCMD_PROC_CURTHREAD
DCMD_PROC_GETGREG
DCMD_PROC_GETFREG
DCMD_PROC_RUN
DCMD_PROC_STOP
.......

Like the devctl() function and DCMD_ PROC_* command